# android application which takes city name and return latitude and longitude

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

An android application which takes city name as input and return longitude and latitude of the city.

```
Which method i should used to do it?
What changes will be needed in android manifest file?
```

Comment: Use Google Geocoding API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: you have to use reverse geocoding which return you latlng when you pass address.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Forward GeoCoding like this:

```
if(Geocoder.isPresent()){
    try {
        String location = "MyLocation";
        Geocoder gcoder = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> addresses= gcoder.getFromLocationName(location, 5); // get the found Address Objects

        List<LatLng> ll = new ArrayList<LatLng>(addresses.size()); // A list to save the coordinates if they are available
        for(Address addr : addresses){
            if(addr.hasLatitude() && addr.hasLongitude()){
                ll.add(new LatLng(addr.getLatitude(), addr.getLongitude();
            }  
        }  
    } catch (IOException e) {
         // handle the exception
    }
}
```

You will require permission for Internet in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Here is a [blog](http://ramsandroid4all.blogspot.in/2013/12/forward-geocoding-example.html) that can help you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can You Tell What Is List<LatLng> here.? Its Error Showing List Can Not Be Resolved To A Type

Comment: LatLng will be a custom class. You will have to create it. It will contain just 2 variable declaration for latitude, longitude and their getter setter @user3147721.

Comment: I would never have imagined such thing exists on android! Thanks